# How to permanently remove widget from screen

Tags: flutter, widget

Is is possible to remove a widget from the tree ?

I've dynamically added some widgets based on my list.
When I click on "remove", the item is removed from the List, but it doesn't refresh my layout.

What do I miss ?

this is how my CTA is made

```
TextButton removeFromSavedPublication = TextButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    print("remove");
    bool removed = await UserWS.removePublicationSaved(widget.publication);
    if (removed) {
      /* TODO: remove from the UI */
      /* setState(() {
        this.widget.listPublications.removeAt(widget.index);
        print(widget.listPublications);
      }); */
    }
  },
);
```

And this is my widgets loop (getSavedPublication)

```
Column getSavedPublications(List<Publication> listPublication) {
    List<Publication> activites = listPublication;

    if (activites.isEmpty) {
      Container empty = Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            AppLocalizations.of(context).no_pub.removeEscape(),
            style: kNoResult,
          ),
        ),
      );
      list.add(empty);
    } else {
      for (int i = 0; i < listPublication.length; i++) {
        PublicationSingle item = PublicationSingle(
          publication: listPublication[i],
          index: i,
          type: "saved",
          listPublications: listPublication,
          listPubWidgets: list,
        );
        list.add(item);
      }
    }

    Column column = Column(
      children: list,
    );

    return column;
  }
```

And how is my code loaded

```
FutureBuilder(
          future: loadPublication,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              List<Publication> listPublication = snapshot.data;
              return getSavedPublications(listPublication);
            } else {
              return Center(
                child: SizedBox(
                  height: 25,
                  width: 25,
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
              );
            }
          },
        )
```

Comment: Can you show us the getSavedPublications function

Comment: I've updated my post